# Why is Weng-Chiang called the 'Butcher of Brisbane'?

Tags: doctor-who

The "Talons of Weng-Chiang" is one the story cycles of the Fourth Doctor's which found critical acclaim. In this story, Magnus Greel runs away from the 51st Century to pose as a Chinese magician in Victorian Britain. In the 51st century, he was a minister of justice for the Supreme Alliance and responsible for 100,00 deaths which apparently earned him the epithet *'the Butcher of Brisbane'*

This sounds like a very odd name choice for the 51st century. I would have expected something more exotic (to signify that we're in the future) rather than a title that comes out of the 19th-century colonialism.

**What does Brisbane refer to here and how did he earn this nickname?**

Comment: Fella had a great little stall at the market in Rocklea, best steaks for your barbie in the whole city.

Answer (score 5):

You've asked 2 questions — Why 'The Butcher of Brisbane'; and what does 'Brisbane' refer to?

'The Butcher of [x]' is a typical sensationalist nickname given to mass-murderers. In real history, there have been several infamous killers given this title, likely by the media. Some of these were killers acting alone, but in other cases, they were war criminals such as Reinhard Heydrich, 'The Butcher of Prague', a Nazi responsible for many deaths in concentration camps.

When 'The Talons of Weng-Chiang' was broadcast, it was likely just thought up as a throwaway line to imply that the character had an infamous history of brutality and to make him scarier.

Since that broadcast, a Big Finish audio production 'The Butcher of Brisbane' has expanded on the story and confirmed that it *is* Brisbane, Australia. The Fifth Doctor and Tegan, who is originally from the city, return to visit her father in the 1980s but accidentally arrive in the 51st century. Magnus Greel is in power as 'Minister of Justice' and is throwing people in labour camps which are evidently an allegory for the Nazi concentration camps. Greel has people sent to the camps for crimes against his state, but there they are used as human experimentation subjects.

As the events of this audio drama occur (with respect to Greel's timeline) *before* the Fourth Doctor meets him in 'Talons', it is his actions at this time that evidently earn him the nickname 'The Butcher of Brisbane'.

Comment: Why does he have the name then?

Comment: @Valorum I've answered the OP's question 'What does Brisbane refer to here?'. I don't think I should answer something that is made quite clear in an episode titled 'The Butcher of Brisbane' - the OP's research is very poor in that area. If you think the OP's question is poor, please don't mark down my answer because of that. If his question gets deleted, so will my answer.

Comment: A much improved answer and one that addresses the (implicit) question asked.